# Problema con guardar datos de dos actividades distintas en Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, hashmap

Tengo dos `Activities`, `PostActivity.java` y `MapsPublisherActivity.java`. `PostActivity.java` guarda toda la información relacionada con el `post`, por ejemplo: `postimage, postid, description, publisher`, etc., el código lo tenéis abajo de dicha `Activity`. Luego, en el `MapsPublisherActivity.java` guardo los datos relacionados con la ubicación en el mapa del post, `Latitude` y `Longitude`. En `MapsPublisherActivity.java` utilizo el `HashMap<String, Double>` para guardar los datos y en PostActivity.java utilizo el `HashMap<String, Object>`.

Datos del `PostActivity.java` se guardan antes y luego te lleva a la página `MapsPublisherActivity.java` para elegir la ubicación del evento y se guardan ahora el `Latitude` y `Longitude`.

Ya que los datos del `PostActivity.java` están guardados en `Firebase` quiero que el `Latitude` y `Longitude` acaben debajo del mismo nodo en `Firebase`, por lo cual tengo que hacer que encuentren los otros datos y se guarden allí con la demás información. No sé cómo hacerlo, llevo ya varios días con el mismo problema y espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.

Abajo tenéis el código de las dos `Activities` y una imagen de cómo se están guardando los datos actualmente... Quiero cambiarlo para que todo acabe debajo del mismo nodo. Además me gustaría mantener las dos `Activities` separadas y no trasladar la información de `MapsPublisherActivity.java` a `PostActivity.java`. Por favor, ayudadme. Gracias.

Tal vez sea alguno de estos que debería utilizar, pero no sé cual...
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-hashmap-in-java-with-examples/

[image: Firebase]

**MapsPublisherActivity.java**

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                String location = searchView.getQuery().toString();
                List<Address> addressList = null;

                if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivityPublisher.this);
                    try {
                        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (addressList != null)
                        if (addressList.size() > 0) {
                            final Address address = addressList.get(0);
                            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(location).draggable(true));
                            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10));

                            final LocationHelper locationHelper = new LocationHelper(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

                            buttonDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                    //Trying to make location data appear in Posts instead of Event Location.
                                    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");

                                    String postid = reference.push().getKey();

                                    hashmapLocation = new HashMap<>();
                                    hashmapLocation.put("latitude", address.getLatitude());
                                    hashmapLocation.put("longitude", address.getLongitude());

                                    reference.child(postid).setValue(hashmapLocation);

                                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").child(postid).setValue(locationHelper)
                                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivityPublisher.this, "Event location saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    } else {
                                                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivityPublisher.this, "Event locations hasn't been saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });

                                    finish();
                                }
                            });


                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MapsActivityPublisher.this, "Modify search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                }

                return false;
            }
```

**PostsActivity.java**

```
                        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");

                        String postid = reference.push().getKey();

                        hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap.put("postid", postid);
                        hashMap.put("postimage", myUrl);
                        hashMap.put("description", txt_description.getText().toString());
                        hashMap.put("text_event", txt_event.getText().toString());
                        hashMap.put("text_location", txt_location.getText().toString());
                        hashMap.put("text_date_time", txt_date_time.getText().toString());
                        hashMap.put("publisher", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        hashMap.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

                        reference.child(postid).setValue(hashMap);

                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Unsuccessful. Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Image Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

**Código modificado**

```
buttonDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                    //Trying to make location data appear in Posts instead of Event Location.
                                    final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
                                    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                                Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                                                if (post.getPostid() != null) {
                                                    hashmapLocation = new HashMap<>();
                                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                                                        hashmapLocation.putIfAbsent("latitude", address.getLatitude());
                                                        hashmapLocation.putIfAbsent("longitude", address.getLongitude());

                                                        reference.child(post.getPostid()).setValue(hashmapLocation).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivityPublisher.this, "Event location saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                } else {
                                                                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivityPublisher.this, "Event locations hasn't been saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        });

                                                        finish();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando vas a guardar los datos de geoposicion estas consiguiendo el postid de esta forma:

```
String postid = reference.push().getKey();
```

Esto te va a devolver un ID nuevo cada vez que lo ejecutes, entonces te crea un post distinto en lugar de agregar los datos al post que ya existe.

Lo unico que tenes que hacer para solucionarlo sera usar el mismo postid que usaste para cargar los datos del `PostActivity`

---

Hay otro problema en como estas guardando los datos. Cuando usas `setValue()` vas a pisar los datos puestas en esa key, siendo la key el post, cuando le pones `setValue()` remplazas todos los valores que tenga ese post por los nuevos que le estas pasando. Una opcion seria pasarle todos parametros del post para que al pisarse no se pierdan.
Lo que yo te recomiendo, para este caso en particular, es que lo hagas asi:

```
reference.child(postid).child("latitude").setValue(address.getLatitude());
reference.child(postid).child("longitude").setValue(address.getLongitude());
```

Comment: Me puedes decir si el código que acabo de subir te parece bien? Es que no lo estoy consiguiendo, no sé lo que estoy haciendo mal...

Comment: no creo que este bien que hagas el cambio dentro de un foreach pero nose bien que intentas hacer, con lo que respecta a lo de usar el id del post correspondientee me parece que si esta bien.

Comment: Tío, estoy a punto de conseguirlo creo, ahora por lo menos está encontrado el ```postid``` del post y se graba allí el ```Latitude``` y ```Longitude```. Lo único es que ahora se están borrando los otros datos ```description, postimage, publisher```, etc. al grabar el ```Latitude``` y ```Longitude```. Sabrás lo que tengo que hacer para resolverlo?

Comment: Bien! deja que edito la respuesta y te resuelvo eso.

Comment: Vale, gracias bro!

Comment: Bro, te puedo hablar por el chat? Casi funciona, pero ahora el ```Latitude``` y ```Longitude``` se cambian para cada ```post``` cada vez que subo un nuevo ```post```. Voy a aceptar tu respuesta, pero me puedes decir lo que tengo que hacer para evitar que el ```Latitude``` y ```Longitude``` se cambiasen cada vez que subo un post nuevo. Es decir que cada post tenga su ```Latitude``` y ```Longitude``` unicos… O dime por aqui lo que tengo que hacer para evitarlo

Comment: si claro, nose como se hace para pasar al chat, pero si no hay problema. Me parece que eso te esta pasando por el foreach que le metiste, ahi le estas aplicando esa latitud y longitud a todos los post.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103111/discussion-between-johnnnn-and-erick-silva).

Comment: Tío, te importa ir al chat un momento? He hecho todo lo que me dijiste con el intent y tal, pero no se están guardando ahora el Latitude y Longitude. A ver si me puedes decir qué he hecho mal...